# mySQL ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK Starting with TODAY

Tags: mysql

I have a List of events that occur on various days weekly.
I would like my query to return the results sorted by day of the week starting with today.

```
'Meeting_Day' = Sunday,  Monday, Tuesday...
'Day_of_Week' = 1, 2, 3...

SELECT Meeting_Day, Day_of_Week, 
    Day_of_Week + (Day_of_Week - DAYOFWEEK(NOW())) as x FROM `meetings` ORDER BY x
```

This is probably simple for the pros but I am no pro.

Answer (score 0):

I looked it over a bit more and found that I could do it thustly.

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  If(Day_of_Week < DAYOFWEEK(Now()), (Day_of_Week + 7), Day_of_Week) as SDAY 
FROM `meetings` 
ORDER BY SDAY
```